# How to colorize the errors in tsc output?

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

When developing a typescript project I run the compiler in watch mode:

```
tsc --watch
```

Yet when an error appears, I find it hard to discern in the output as I have plain formatted text:

[image: error output of tsc: <code>src/core/SnowWhite/Cruise/SnowWhiteCruiseClient.ts(10,52): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'favfav'.</code>]

Often time I don't even read it, as there are multiple outputs from previous runs.

I currently am trying to ease my pain by grepping for errors in order to mark those line in red:

```
tsc -w | egrep --color '.*error.*|$'
```

yet that feels hackish. Is there a more easy way to get errors printed out nicely in typescript?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

TypeScript supports multiple [compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html), and one of them is `pretty`:

> Stylize errors and messages using color and context.

Alas, it defaults to `false` so you have to enable it in your `.tsconfig`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "pretty": true
    }
}
```

Then you get colors and more context information:

[image: Screenshot of tsc with pretty enabled to provide colors and more context on errors]

Comment: Thanks. `"pretty"` now defaults to `true`. _Unless piping to another program or redirecting output to a file_. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `--pretty` to ensure that the error messages piped into another command or dumped into a file get colors and other nice treatment:

```sh
tsc --pretty | egrep --color '.*error.*|$'

# or, if you prefer to dump to a file and read from it:
tsc --pretty > errs.txt
less -R errs.txt
```